# PHP Form Using Session Showing the Link after Submit

Tags: php, session

My goal to this form is to use `SESSION` (I've finished the `COOKIE` section from w3school website) in order for a user to log in using simple PHP no database but in doing so can only have one session once user has logged in and clicked the little 'remember' me. Anyway, I just want to demonstrate that user can only access the link one time but that when he/she clicked on 'remember' will remember them nevertheless. **I was trying to refresh the browser but link doesn't disappear.** Example,

Initial form shows:

```
Name: _________
Email: __________  () Remember   SUBMIT
```

After clicking the 'remember' should show the name and email entered.

```
John
john@email.com

Here is your link: <some link>
```

When you refresh your browser link should disappear but will remember name and email entered.

```
John
john@email.com
```

Here's the code... any ideas?

```
// Session Starts
session_start();

// Vaidation, Sanitation and if the form is submitted



 if (!$fnameErr && !$lnameErr && !$emailErr && !$phoneErr && !$subjectErr  && !$messageErr)  {

   $_SESSIOIN['views'] = 1;
   if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
     $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
   }


    // SESSION
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
  $customer_name = $_SESSION['name'];
if (!($customer_name)) {
  $customer_name = $_POST['name'];
}
  $customer_email = $_SESSION['email'];
if (!($customer_email)) {
  $customer_email = $_POST['email'];
}

    }


     if( ($visits > 2) || ($_SESSION['visits'] > $expire)) { 
     echo "Sorry you've downloaded your the file already.";         }
     else {
     echo '<a href="download.php"><b>Download our PDF brochure!</b></a>';        
     }              


    } else {
        echo '<div id="error">' . $errors . '<br /></div>';
    }



?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Name:
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br />";
  }
else {
?> 
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" size="25" /><br />
<?php } ?>

Email:
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email']."<br /><br />";

  }
else {
?>  
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" size="25"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
<?php } ?>


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `session` and not `cookie`?

Comment: @DevlshOne because I'm trying to demonstrate what I've learned using COOKIE and now I'm on SESSION rather.

Comment: Does fixing ```$_SESSIOIN['views'] = 1;``` help at all?

Comment: @jameslafferty I've tried this section separately and should work generally. I'm not sure what is causing it to still show the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made is so that if `$_SESSION['views'] < 2` will show the link but won't do so more than that.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['views'])){
  $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;  

}
else {
  $_SESSION['views']=1;
}  


if ($_SESSION['views'] < 2) {
  echo "Here's your link"; 
}
else {
echo "You have viewed this about ". $_SESSION['views']." times already."; 
}
```